# RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed

Tags: deep-learning, multiclass-classification, pytorch

I am referring this previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981101/runtimeerror-assertion-cur-target-0-cur-target-n-classes-failed) in stack-overflow which remains unsolved till now.

I am facing same problem with `pytorch` when I am solving multiclass classification.

Here is my exception

> RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1532501501514\work\aten\src\thnn\generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:93

I have added whole code of mine with the dataset I am trying with but still get stuck on that

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul 11 22:41:07 2019

@author: Ananda Mohon Ghosh
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.utils.data as utils
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms, models
import torch.optim as optim




class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.classificaion =nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(16, 12),
            nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)            
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        clsf = self.classificaion(x)
        return clsf

def oneHotCode(y):
    y = y-min(y)
    nOfClasses = len(set(y)) 
    labels = y.reshape(len(y), 1)
    return (labels == torch.arange(nOfClasses).reshape(1, nOfClasses)).long()

def batchData(xBatch, yBatch):
    return np.concat((xBatch, yBatch),axis=1)

def findMinMax(df):
    #find max-min
    minimum = 999999
    maximum =  -999999

    for di in  df:
        tMin = min(di)
        tMax = max(di)
        if(tMin<minimum):
            minimum = tMin
        if(tMax>maximum):
            maximum = tMax
    return maximum, minimum


dataFrame = pd.read_csv('data/features_test_encoded16_ds1_batch_sig.csv')
dataFrameValues = dataFrame.values

availabelCuda = torch.device("cuda:2" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print('Availabel CUDA ', availabelCuda)

#variables
num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 128
learning_rate = 1e-3
weight_decay = 1e-5
momentum = 0.9


clsf = Net()
model = clsf.to(availabelCuda)

lossFunc= nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,  weight_decay=weight_decay)


observations =  dataFrameValues.shape[0]
featureSetLength = dataFrameValues.shape[1]
featureSet = dataFrameValues[0:len(dataFrameValues), 0:featureSetLength-1 ]
maximum, minimum =findMinMax(featureSet)

featureSet = (featureSet-minimum)/(maximum-minimum)

labelSet = dataFrameValues[0:len(dataFrameValues), featureSetLength-1 ]

Xtrain = featureSet[0:int(observations*0.7), :]
Xtest = featureSet[int(observations*0.7):observations, :]
Ytrain = labelSet[0:int(observations*0.7)]
Ytest = labelSet[int(observations*0.7):observations]

X = torch.Tensor(Xtrain)
Y = torch.Tensor(Ytrain.reshape(-1,1))
trainDataset = utils.TensorDataset(X, Y)


dataloaderTrain = utils.DataLoader(trainDataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

print('Model running on ', availabelCuda)


for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for xX, yY in dataloaderTrain:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        dataX = Variable(xX).to(availabelCuda)
        dataY = Variable(yY.long()).to(availabelCuda)

        outclass = clsf(dataX)
        print(outclass.type(), dataY.view(-1).type())

        loss = lossFunc(outclass, dataY.view(-1))
        optimizer.zero_grad()               # clear gradients for this training step
        loss.backward()                     # backpropagation, compute gradients
        optimizer.step()
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, '| train loss: %.4f' % loss.data.numpy()) #CPU
```

and here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tstwfbx94w4l327/features_test_encoded16_ds1_batch_sig.csv?dl=0) of my dataset. Actually, I was hoping that I have problem with data normalization but eventually I couldn't solve it and still have this issue. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after 4 days I got my solution eventually. I figured it out that my classes are started from 1 to 12, so, in total I had 12 classes.

The problem was appearing when I was about to calculate the predicted class vs actual class loss with the loss function. Instead of having start from 1 that function always from class 0 instead of 1 and continuously look for 0 to 12 which indicated it do have 13 classes in total which generates an exception.

So how do I solved that? I just docked 1 form each labels and shifted it from 0 to 11 and it went fine. That's how I solved the issue. Mention, I got couple of solution at PyTorch forum regarding the same issue and those wasn't helpful at all, literally!